# Is there anything I can do to make my question answered?

Tags: support, questions

I asked a [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/166560/7-views-display-filters-in-other-formats) but no one answered it yet. Is there anything I should do, or is my question ambiguous? Please guide me on asking the right question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considered that you asked the question on a weekend and that is summer, I would not expect any answer so quickly.

It is also the question that probably make them puzzled. I could imagine them wondering:

- What doesn't he find so confusing?
- What does he want to show, and where?
- What exactly is he trying to achieve?
- Is he asking for code?

Since the low activity on the site during the weekends, nobody commented to ask what they find not clear. Expect them to first comment, and then answer, if they are able to do it, or if the question is clear enough for them. Remember that Stack Exchange is for answering a well defined question, not for guessing the answer that helps you.

What you can do is make your question clearer, and add those details they need to answer it. See what comments they add, and add the details they need by editing your question.

Comment: thanks! your answered helped me a lot!